# Plotagon alternatives for Ubuntu

Tags: animations

Are there any **Plotagon** alternatives for Ubuntu? It would be jolly helpful if it were to be opensource and free.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the website alternativesto.net. They specify opensource and platform : https://alternativeto.net/software/goanimate/

[Vyond](https://www.vyond.com/) looks nice at first glance, since it's web-based you can use it on anything including ubuntu (if you use google-chrome as a browser, not chromium).

since you were using paying software before I assume you have no problem switching to another paid solution?

there's also [Explee](https://explee.com/fr/) and [nawmalMAKE](http://www.xtranormal.com/) 
https://alternativeto.net/software/plotagon/

out of all of them Vyond will probably suit your needs the most.

I would be remiss if I didn't mention the DIY approach : [Blender](https://www.blender.org/). but I grasp that you don't wish to have to model and animate yourself.